# Python for loop: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new with Python,
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

x = [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 10, 5]
y = [4, 4, 4, 4, 9, 4, 2, 9]

def unitvector1 (x,y):
    looplim=(len(x)+1)

    for i in range (0,looplim):
        z=i+1
        alfa = np.arccos((x[i]*x[z])+(y[i]*y[z])) / ((np.sqrt(x[i] ^ 2+y[i] ^ 2) * np.sqrt(x[z] ^ 2+y[z] ^ 2))) 

        beta =+ (180-alfa)

    return (beta)

temp=unitvector1(x,y)

print(temp)
```

And I am getting this error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

I tried to do it with two for loops but it did not work.

Your help is much needed, Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: ```looplim``` shouldn't really be ```len(x) + 1``` since ```range(0, looplim)``` will give you a range of ```0``` to ```len(x)```;  but while the length of ```x``` is ```len(x)```,  the indices of ```x``` is from ```0``` to ```len(x) - 1```

Comment: you can use try and except

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
looplim=len(x) 
for i in range(looplim-1):
alfa = np.arccos((x[i]*x[z])+(y[i]*y[z])) / ((np.sqrt(x[i] ^ 2+y[i] ^ 2) * 
np.sqrt(x[z] ^ 2+y[z] ^ 2)))
```

for each iteration value of "alfa" is nan

Answer (score 3):

Lists are indexed starting from 0, so for a list of length, say, 13, the last valid index is 12, i.e., 1 less than the length.

When you do `looplim=(len(x)+1)` and then `for i in range (0,looplim)`, the last value of `i` is `looplim-1` which is equal to `len(x)`, so it's the length rather than 1 less than that.

Answer (score 1):

remove + 1 from looplim=(len(x)+1) and z = i+1 then run the code !

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, If I will delete z=i+1 I would get a not-defined name. I am not completely following

Comment: Hello my friend... i meant you remove + 1 from z variable definition... so your z variable is equal i . Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first u should look at your variable z. When i=7 z=8 and there are no eight’s index element in x array.
Second, idk why you try “looplim”. If you want to do operations with n and n+1 elements in this way we can add next:

```
   def unitvector1 (x,y):
      for i in range (len(x)-1):
          z=i+1
          if z==len(x)+1:
              z=0
          alfa = np.arccos((x[i]*x[z])+(y[i]*y[z])) / ((np.sqrt(x[i] ^ 2+y[i] ^ 2) * np.sqrt(x[z] ^ 2+y[z] ^ 2))) 

          beta =+ (180-alfa)

    return (beta)
```

But it’s not working! Because arccos(alpha) should have alpha<|1|

If you can explain what do you want to count, maybe we can help you